# Ionic 3 facebook login issue

Tags: ionic3

Ionic facebook login shows error Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
```

I am following the document of v3. But dont know why its showing this error i already added facebook in app.module.ts also. Any one know how to sole this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the response is an `[object Object]`, you can able to identify the error by adding this line

```
.catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', JSON.stringify(e)));
```

instead of

```
.catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
```

If the facebook login response is `Facebook log in Error “User canceled Dialog” - 4201.` To solve this error ensure that facebook session is logged out in your application.

Refer to the below website:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/facebook-login-error-user-cancelled-dialog-4201/101022